# Firefox or Chrome add-on to modify cookie timeout?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, cookies

I have a website where I log in. It has a "short" timeout, most likely set in a cookie, so if I leave it for around ten minutes it will often say: "sorry, log in again".

Are there any Firefox/Google Chrome add-ons that can modify the cookie to set a bigger timeout? Since the website uses HTTPS, a proxy is not really a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an add-on for Firefox that may be what you want:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-n-edit-cookies/

It is said that this addon works perfectly on Firefox 4 although the description never says that. However, I can't assure you that for I've never used it myself.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: I will try this one out, i hope i could modify the "expire" time :P